# How to set up multiple RMI servers on different machines?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, rmi

I have an RMI CalculatorServer and a CalculatorClient class.
For the purpose of load balancing, I want to know how to set up several servers, each on a separate machine, so that multiple clients can access any of the servers.

**CalculatorServer.java**

```
public class CalculatorServer implements Serializable{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(7000);
            CalculatorImpl ci = new CalculatorImpl();
            reg.bind("calc", ci);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server Started.");
        }
        catch(RemoteException e){
            System.out.println("Server Remote Exception: "+e);
        }
        catch(AlreadyBoundException e){
            System.out.println("Server Already Bound Exception: "+e);
        }
    }
}
```

**CalculatorClient.java**

```
public class CalculatorClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter first number :");
        int x = sn.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter second number :");
        int y = sn.nextInt();

        try{
            Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1", 7000);
            CalculatorInterface ci = (CalculatorInterface)reg.lookup("calc");

            int sum = ci.add(x, y);

            System.out.println("Sum is: "+sum);
        }
        catch(RemoteException e){
            System.out.println(" Client Remote Exception: "+e);
        }
        catch(NotBoundException e){
            System.out.println(" Client Remote Exception: "+e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define 'create'. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I want to have multiple copies of the class CalculatorServer.java (along with its implementations) on each server. Then any client must be able to access any server.

Comment: And your problem with doing that is what?

Comment: The problem is that a client has restricted access to only 1 server. In my CalculatorClient.java, I have the following line which "connects" to a specific host using a specific IP address: Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1", 7000);. I would like to have a pool of servers, where clients can access any of the servers.

Comment: I think you have discovered one of the reasons that JavaEE was invented...

Comment: @Steve C can you please tell me why. I didn't understand it.

Comment: So you have to change your client to get the IP address of the server from outside. Hardly an insoluble problem, and not one that is peculiar to RMI.

Comment: I have found a solution to it. Any suggestions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have a number of servers (e.g 5). You can populate an arraylist using all 5 IP addresses. Then each time a client makes a request, select a random server IP from the arraylist.

```
public class generateServerIP {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
        al.add("172.62.22.103");
        al.add("172.62.22.123");
        al.add("172.62.22.15");
        al.add("172.62.22.187");
        al.add("172.62.22.110");

        int ip = new Random().nextInt(al.size());
        System.out.println(al.get(ip));
    }  
}
```

To connect to a server use the following:

```
Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(ip, 7000);
```

The nextInt(int n) method uses uniform distribution, therefore the probability of choosing any ip from the arraylist is equal to the probability of choosing any other ip.